# Dismount / mount connected USB disks

Tags: powershell

I'm writing Powershell script for dismounting connected USB disks, after that it would run some PS code and then it should mount the USB drives again.

The Powershell script is for Windows 7 above and for MS Server 2012 above. I think that the best way for mounting ejected USB disks will be through disable/enable USB Mass Storage Device in Device Manager because after that an USB disk can be mounted again. When an USB disk is dismounted from Main Panel then appropriated USB Mass Storage Device in Device Manager will change its state to safe removal (error 47), so according to this "error" the USB disk is easily identifiable.

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/remount-ejected-usb-drive-windows

```
#Identify connected USB disk/s and dismounting 
$usbDrives = @(Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_DiskDrive -Filter 'InterfaceType = "USB"' -KeyOnly | Get-CimAssociatedInstance - ResultClassName Win32_DiskPartition -KeyOnly | Get-CimAssociatedInstance - ResultClassName Win32_LogicalDisk | ForEach-Object{$_.deviceid})

for ($i = 0; $i -le ($usbDrives.length - 1); $i += 1) {
    $Eject =  New-Object -comObject Shell.Application
    $Eject.NameSpace(17).ParseName($usbDrives[$i]).InvokeVerb("Eject")
}

#Some code...

#Getting USB Mass Storage Devices with error 47 and disable/enable 
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | Where-Object{$_.ConfigManagerErrorCode -eq 47} | Select-Object Name, DeviceID | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false;
    $_ | Enable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false;
}
```

If I use my script for ejecting connected an USB disk, then the USB disk will disconnect, but the USB Mass Storage Device in Device Manager won't change its state to error 47, its state will stay as connected and I can't mount connected USB disks.

Please know somebody, how to write or repair this PS code for dismounting and mounting connected USB disk(s)?

Thank you

Comment: Are you running this script as Admin?

Comment: _I am able_  to change the state of a _USB Mass Storage Device_ to error 47 (programmatically, from a Powershell script). However, I'm constantly failing to get the USB device back to its operational state without unplugging and replugging it (or, without following your link but it's a manual doing as well)…

Comment: @JosefZ If you are able to change the state of a USB Mass Storage Device to error 47 from PowerShell, please can you tell me how do it? It would help me a lot because I didn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the state of a USB Mass Storage Device to error 47 *programmatically*, we need to call the [`CM_Request_Device_Eject` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_request_device_ejectw) for a device with the `CM_DEVCAP_REMOVABLE` bit set in its `Capabilities` property. We can verify that it's parent of the USB drive itself (e.g. using the *Config manager*).

To do that from **PowerShell in Windows**, define and call a native Windows API (see e.g. [*Example 4* in the *Add-Type* cmdlet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-6#examples)).

First, define the `[Usb.Api]` type with the following basic functions:

- `CM_Locate_DevNode` - to get the root node of the device tree.
- `CM_Get_Parent` - to get the device ID with the `CM_DEVCAP_REMOVABLE` bit set (important!).
- `CM_Request_Device_Eject` - the key function allows you to safely remove the device.

Then, use it as follows (in `56496356a.ps1` script I omit the *disable/enable* part as it requires elevated session, see also `56496356b.ps1` and `56496356c.ps1` scripts in the addendum below)

```
# 56496356a.ps1
Function Remove-USBSafely {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [PSObject]$usbDrive # necessary: a `PNPDeviceID` property
    )
  Begin {
    try   { $null = [Usb.Api]                } 
    catch { . D:\PShell\tests\Set-UsbApi.ps1 } # change path to match your circumstances
  }
  Process {
    $DevInst = $DevInstParent = 0
    # get the root node of the device tree
    $DevNodeA = [Usb.Api]::CM_Locate_DevNode(
                            [ref]$devinst,$usbDrive.PNPDeviceID,0)
    # get the device ID; Capabilities bit CM_DEVCAP_REMOVABLE (Important!)
    $DevNodeP = [Usb.Api]::CM_Get_Parent(
                            [ref]$DevInstParent,$devinst,0)
    # safely remove the device
    try {
        $aux = [Usb.Api]::Eject($DevInstParent)
        switch ( $aux ) {
            "OK"    { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Success $aux`: $usbDrive";
                        return  0 } # device removed
            default { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Fail $aux`: $usbDrive";
                        return -1 } # failed: maybe some locked files?
        }
    } 
    catch { 
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Blocked $usbDrive";
        return -5 }                 # failed: maybe some locked files?
  }
}

# Identify connected USB disk/s
$usbDrives = @(
 Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskDrive -Filter 'InterfaceType = "USB"' -OutVariable DiskDrive      -PipelineVariable Disk |
  Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_DiskPartition -OutVariable DiskPartition  -PipelineVariable Part |
  Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_LogicalDisk   -OutVariable DiskLogical |
   Select-Object `
        @{n='DriveLetter'; e={$_.DeviceID}},
        @{n='PNPDeviceID'; e={$Disk.PNPDeviceID}},
        # collect the following properties merely for debugging purposes
        @{n='VolumeName' ; e={$_.VolumeName}},
        @{n='DiskModel'  ; e={$Disk.model}},
        @{n='Disk'       ; e={$Disk.deviceid}},
        @{n='Partition'  ; e={$Part.name}}
)

$usbDrives | ForEach-Object {
    $auxResult = $_ | Remove-USBSafely
    if ( $auxResult -ne 0 ) {
        ### eject the drive anyway ?
        # $Eject =  New-Object -comObject Shell.Application
        # $Eject.NameSpace(17).ParseName($_.DriveLetter).InvokeVerb("Eject")
    }
}

#Some code...
```

The `[Usb.Api]` type is defined in `Set-UsbApi.ps1` script as follows:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
# D:\PShell\tests\Set-UsbApi.ps1
try   { $null = [Usb.Api]                } 
catch { # C# signature (pinvoke)
$script:UsbApiCode = @"
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Usb
{
    public class Api
    {
        public enum PNP_VETO_TYPE
        {
            Ok,
            TypeUnknown,
            LegacyDevice,
            PendingClose,
            WindowsApp,
            WindowsService,
            OutstandingOpen,
            Device,
            Driver,
            IllegalDeviceRequest,
            InsufficientPower,
            NonDisableable,
            LegacyDriver,
            InsufficientRights
        }

        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int CM_Request_Device_Eject(
            IntPtr devinst, 
            out PNP_VETO_TYPE pVetoType, 
            System.Text.StringBuilder pszVetoName, 
            int ulNameLength, 
            int ulFlags);           // 0 (not used)
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        public static extern int CM_Locate_DevNode(
            ref int pdnDevInst, 
            string pDeviceID, 
            int ulFlags);           // 0..4, 7
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Get_Parent(
            out UInt32 pdnDevInst,
            UInt32 dnDevInst,
            int ulFlags);           // Not used, must be zero

        public static string Eject(int devinst)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(255);
            PNP_VETO_TYPE veto;
            IntPtr dev = new IntPtr(devinst);
            int hr = CM_Request_Device_Eject(dev, out veto, sb, sb.Capacity, 0);
            if (hr != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(hr);
            return veto.ToString();
        }

         // JosefZ 2019-06-10
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Disable_DevNode(
            UInt32 dnDevInst,
            int ulFlags);           // 0..4, 8, 0xF
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Enable_DevNode(
            UInt32 dnDevInst,
            int ulFlags);           // must be 0
        /* 
        The CM_Setup_DevNode function restarts a device instance that is
        not running because there is a problem with the device configuration.
        */
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Setup_DevNode(
            UInt32 dnDevInst,
            int     ulFlags);       // 0 or 4
    }
        public enum CONFIGRET
        {
            CR_SUCCESS                  , // 0x00
            CR_DEFAULT                  , // 0x01
            CR_OUT_OF_MEMORY            , // 0x02
            CR_INVALID_POINTER          , // 0x03
            CR_INVALID_FLAG             , // 0x04
            CR_INVALID_DEVNODE          , // 0x05 // CR_INVALID_DEVINST
            CR_INVALID_RES_DES          , // 0x06
            CR_INVALID_LOG_CONF         , // 0x07
            CR_INVALID_ARBITRATOR       , // 0x08
            CR_INVALID_NODELIST         , // 0x09
            CR_DEVNODE_HAS_REQS         , // 0x0A // CR_DEVINST_HAS_REQS
            CR_INVALID_RESOURCEID       , // 0x0B
            CR_DLVXD_NOT_FOUND          , // 0x0C        // WIN 95 ONLY
            CR_NO_SUCH_DEVNODE          , // 0x0D // CR_NO_SUCH_DEVINST
            CR_NO_MORE_LOG_CONF         , // 0x0E
            CR_NO_MORE_RES_DES          , // 0x0F
            CR_ALREADY_SUCH_DEVNODE     , // 0x10 // CR_ALREADY_SUCH_DEVINST
            CR_INVALID_RANGE_LIST       , // 0x11
            CR_INVALID_RANGE            , // 0x12
            CR_FAILURE                  , // 0x13
            CR_NO_SUCH_LOGICAL_DEV      , // 0x14
            CR_CREATE_BLOCKED           , // 0x15
            CR_NOT_SYSTEM_VM            , // 0x16        // WIN 95 ONLY
            CR_REMOVE_VETOED            , // 0x17
            CR_APM_VETOED               , // 0x18
            CR_INVALID_LOAD_TYPE        , // 0x19
            CR_BUFFER_SMALL             , // 0x1A
            CR_NO_ARBITRATOR            , // 0x1B
            CR_NO_REGISTRY_HANDLE       , // 0x1C
            CR_REGISTRY_ERROR           , // 0x1D
            CR_INVALID_DEVICE_ID        , // 0x1E
            CR_INVALID_DATA             , // 0x1F
            CR_INVALID_API              , // 0x20
            CR_DEVLOADER_NOT_READY      , // 0x21
            CR_NEED_RESTART             , // 0x22
            CR_NO_MORE_HW_PROFILES      , // 0x23
            CR_DEVICE_NOT_THERE         , // 0x24
            CR_NO_SUCH_VALUE            , // 0x25
            CR_WRONG_TYPE               , // 0x26
            CR_INVALID_PRIORITY         , // 0x27
            CR_NOT_DISABLEABLE          , // 0x28
            CR_FREE_RESOURCES           , // 0x29
            CR_QUERY_VETOED             , // 0x2A
            CR_CANT_SHARE_IRQ           , // 0x2B
            CR_NO_DEPENDENT             , // 0x2C
            CR_SAME_RESOURCES           , // 0x2D
            CR_NO_SUCH_REGISTRY_KEY     , // 0x2E
            CR_INVALID_MACHINENAME      , // 0x2F // NT ONLY
            CR_REMOTE_COMM_FAILURE      , // 0x30 // NT ONLY
            CR_MACHINE_UNAVAILABLE      , // 0x31 // NT ONLY
            CR_NO_CM_SERVICES           , // 0x32 // NT ONLY
            CR_ACCESS_DENIED            , // 0x33 // NT ONLY
            CR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED     , // 0x34
            CR_INVALID_PROPERTY         , // 0x35
            CR_DEVICE_INTERFACE_ACTIVE  , // 0x36
            CR_NO_SUCH_DEVICE_INTERFACE , // 0x37
            CR_INVALID_REFERENCE_STRING , // 0x38
            CR_INVALID_CONFLICT_LIST    , // 0x39
            CR_INVALID_INDEX            , // 0x3A
            CR_INVALID_STRUCTURE_SIZE   , // 0x3B
            NUM_CR_RESULTS              , // 0x3C
        }

}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $script:UsbApiCode
Remove-Variable -Name UsbApiCode -Scope script
}
```

**Addendum** - unsuccessful tries to get the USB device back to its operational state: the *commented* scripts:

**`56496356b.ps1`** using the `Disable-PnpDevice` and `Enable-PnpDevice` cmdlets

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
Begin 
{
    Import-Module PnpDevice
}
Process 
{
#Getting USB Mass Storage Devices with error 47 and disable/enable 
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | Where-Object{$_.ConfigManagerErrorCode -eq 47} | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host $_.Caption -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $_ | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false; ### #Requires -RunAsAdministrator
        Write-Host $_.DeviceID -ForegroundColor Yellow
        pause # Device manager shows `Enable Device`  in the right click menu
              # this means that the device was succesfully disabled
        $_ | Enable-PnpDevice  -Confirm:$false;
              # Device manager shows `Disable Device` in the right click menu
    }
}
```

**`56496356c.ps1`** using the `CM_Disable_DevNode`, `CM_Enable_DevNode` and `CM_Setup_DevNode` functions of the `[Usb.Api]` class:

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
begin {
    try   { $null = [Usb.Api]                } 
    catch { . D:\PShell\tests\Set-UsbApi.ps1 }
    Import-Module PnpDevice
}
Process {

#Getting USB Mass Storage Devices with error 47 and disable/enable 
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | Where-Object{$_.ConfigManagerErrorCode -eq 47} | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host $_.Caption -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $DevInst = 0
        [Usb.CONFIGRET]([Usb.Api]::CM_Locate_DevNode( [ref]$DevInst, $_.PNPDeviceID, 0))
        [Usb.CONFIGRET]([Usb.Api]::CM_Disable_DevNode( $DevInst, 0)) # using any supported flag
        Write-Host $_.DeviceID -ForegroundColor Yellow
        # Device manager shows `Disable Device` constantly in the right click menu
        # this means that the device was NOT disabled keeping its `Enable` state
        # pause
        [Usb.CONFIGRET]([Usb.Api]::CM_Enable_DevNode( $DevInst, 0))
        # pause
        [Usb.CONFIGRET]([Usb.Api]::CM_Setup_DevNode(  $DevInst, 8))  # using any supported flag
    }
}
```

**Acknowledgment**. Great thanks to [Александр AKA Kazun](https://kazunposh.wordpress.com/about/) for his operational complex script in the [Safely remove USB flash (*Безопасное извлечение USB Flash* in Russian original)](https://kazunposh.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-usb-flash/) article.