# Get-WmiObject : Invalid query for Win32_DiskPartition

Tags: powershell

When attempting to run my script then I got the following the error message.  btw ,  I have to use Get-WmiObject for older OSes.

Script :

```
ForEach($link in Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition){
    $partition = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskPartition -Filter "Path = $($link.Antecedent)"
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "System Name" = $partition.SystemName
        "Drive Letter" = $link.Dependent.DeviceID
        "Partition Style" =  $partition.Type
    }
}
```

Error Message :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ForEach($link in Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition){
    $partition = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskPartition -Filter "Path = $($link.Antecedent)"
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "System Name" = $partition.SystemName
        "Drive Letter" = $link.Dependent.DeviceID
        "Partition Style" =  $partition.Type
    }
}
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_DiskPartition where Path = \\SERVER1\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #1""
At line:2 char:18
+ ... partition = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskPartition -Filter "Path = $($link ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
 

System Name Drive Letter Partition Style
----------- ------------ ---------------
                                        
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_DiskPartition where Path = \\SERVER1\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #1, Partition #0""
At line:2 char:18
+ ... partition = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskPartition -Filter "Path = $($link ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
 
                                        
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_DiskPartition where Path = \\SERVER1\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #3, Partition #0""
At line:2 char:18
+ ... partition = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskPartition -Filter "Path = $($link ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
 
                                        
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_DiskPartition where Path = \\SERVER1\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #2, Partition #0""
At line:2 char:18
+ ... partition = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskPartition -Filter "Path = $($link ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: Please take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-tasks--disks-and-file-systems?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: There is managed and unmanaged version of the partition code.  The managed version needs Net 2.0.  Win32_DiskPartition is using windows dll.  See : http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/DeviceIoControl.html

Comment: You are missing quotes around the path in your WMI query. Try with single quotes: `-Filter "Path = '$($link.Antecedent)'"`

Comment: `get-disk | get-partition` ?

Comment: @zett42  like you said I have tried it too. but no luck still same issue.

Comment: @jdweng  Hi Man , care to share your sample script?  thanks again,

Comment: @AndreiOdegov  Hi Andrei ,  I've looked it.  There are VB script.

Answer (score 1):

Pure PowerShell solution based on [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56550602/3439404) (select output properties by your own preference):

```
$ideDrives = @(
 Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_DiskDrive <# -Filter 'InterfaceType = "IDE"' <##> | 
  ForEach-Object {
   $disk = $_
   $partitions = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
                 "{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='$($disk.DeviceID)'} " +
                 "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
   Get-CimInstance -Query $partitions |
    ForEach-Object {
     $partition = $_
     $drives = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
               "{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='$($partition.DeviceID)'} " +
               "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
     Get-CimInstance -Query $drives | 
      ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
          # Disk        = $disk.DeviceID
          # DiskSize    = $disk.Size
          # DiskModel   = $disk.Model
          # PNPDeviceID = $disk.PNPDeviceID
            Partition   = $partition.Name
          # PartSysName = $partition.SystemName
            PartStyle   = $partition.Type
          # RawSize     = $partition.Size
            DriveLetter = $_.DeviceID
            VolumeName  = $_.VolumeName
          # VolumeSize  = $_.Size
          # VolumeFree  = $_.FreeSpace
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
$ideDrives
```

**Output**: `.\SO\76495479.ps1`

```
Partition             PartStyle               DriveLetter VolumeName
---------             ---------               ----------- ----------
Disk #1, Partition #1 Installable File System C:          Win10
Disk #0, Partition #0 Installable File System D:          DataDisk
```

Comment: Thanks , But I need to use this script on older OSes such as 2008R2. AFAIK , does not supported Get-CimInstance cmd-let.  I am assuming , I will use Get-WmiObject. How can I do that ?

Comment: When accessing local data, WMI and CIM are nearly identical except for minor cosmetic differences in the output. Hence, replacing _all_ `Get-CimInstance` with `Get-WmiObject` in script provided, then altered script should work (tested in PowerShell 5.1). Of course, `Get-WmiObject` is unknown in PowerShell Core (version 6+)…

Comment: Thanks ,lastly  I have a disk layout like my screeshot. You can see mypowershell output inside screenshot. it displaying `Logical Disk Manager`  `Installable File System` (MBR) in `Partition Style` column. What's issue?    https://imgur.com/a/NBZcLWW

Comment: @Arbelac it's OK. by [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskpartition), _Type of the partition._ could be any of "Unused"
"12-bit FAT"
"Xenix Type 1"
"Xenix Type 2"
"16-bit FAT"
"Extended Partition"
"MS-DOS V4 Huge"
"Installable File System"
"PowerPC Reference Platform"
"UNIX"
"NTFS"
"Win95 w/Extended Int 13"
"Extended w/Extended Int 13"
"Logical Disk Manager"
"Unknown"

Comment: So , In addition ,How can I add MBR as partition style information to the my output?